# Garden swing hardware

Tags: hardware

I have a garden swing that has broken due to high winds. The part that broke is the part that attaches the canopy to the frame. It looks like this:

[image]

The broken part is where it screws into the canopy on the upper left. The plastic cracked around the screw holes, so it is unlikely that the screws are going to hold. I tried contacting the manufacturer, but apparently there is just no possible way to contact them.

So my question is, is there any way to find some similar type of hardware that could do the same job? The piece on the right inserts into the metal tube of the frame and then those teeth mesh together so you can adjust the angle. And the piece on the left them wraps around the smaller metal tube around the canopy.

Any ideas? Or should I just look to toss the whole swing?

Comment: Worth a look at some keyboard stands, as used on stage for electronic pianos, et al.. They often have the same sort of teeth arrangement, and a couple of attachments for tubing. Or do without the canopy! relocate in a shady place.

Answer (score 1):

The image below does not match the fitting you seek and you may not find exactly that type of fitting, but you may find something that works as well. It may be stronger, as most I found are made of metal:

[image: Pipe railing fittings]

Search for "pipe railing fittings" and examine the many options. The image search from the Google returned so many varieties, I selected one that was close.